# Blender Ocean Modifier time animation not showing in react-three/fiber

Tags: 3d, blender, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm creating a very simple plain in blender and applying the ocean modifier to it. After i configure the modifier and add the time keyframes, I apply the modifier and export it as .gltf . When I upload the file to an online gltfViewer the animation is not detected by it, and the same goes if I try to use the gltf with react-three/fiber. With any other animation things seem to work but the ocean modifier seems to require specific handling. Does anyone have an idea of how to bake the ocean modifier animation properly? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not the exporting as `.gltf` but is with applying the ocean modifier. There is an issue [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57168/apply-ocean-modifier-to-existing-face-plane) that answers the question of applying the ocean modifier. But an even better answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object) about applying the animation. Hope that helps!

Comment: Apparently, blender modifiers are something internal to blender and Three.js can't use them nor "read" them per say when importing the .gltf model. The .mdd shown in your second link is targeted for video production. Anyway, thanks for trying to help but I've changed my approach and now I'm using three.js custom shaders with glsl.